# What is the simplest way in Android to keep an objects value after every app run?

Tags: android, variables, null

What is the simplest way to store a single object value so that the object is not null the next time the app is executed?

for example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    String X = "Hello"
}
```

The next time I run this app, X will still be defined as "Hello".

Comment: I really can't get your question...in the example you give X will be always Hello.

Comment: i think he's after "SharedPreferences" or "Sqlite"

Comment: Sorry if its not clear.. I mean to say when I run the app this activity will define x as hello. Then lets say i close the app, and then rerun it. I still want x to be defined as Hello (if the main activity is run, it will overwrite x to be defined as hello again)..

Comment: You're still not clear.  In the example you give, X will always and can only ever be "Hello".  You can close and reopen your app a million times, it will still be "Hello".  Do you mean that you change the value later, at runtime, and you want to store the changed value?  So, when you first run the app, it's "Hello".  Later, at runtime, you change X to "Goodbye" and it is this changed value that you want to store and retrieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and see which is best for your needs. You probably want to add it to sharedprefs somewhere, which uses a `key/value` pair, if it is lite data. Otherwise, you may want a SQLite DB. But `X` is always going to be "Hello" the way you have it so you will need a function somewhere to set the sharedprefs or whatever you use. I'm assuming you just put that code for simplicity but just pointing that out.